# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha actual y extraer el año de ella desde la creación de la tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Cómo puedo obtener la fecha actual y obtener el año de esa fecha?

```
create table materia
(
    id_materia varchar(4),
    nombre varchar(50),
    facha date,
    Constraint pk_materia primary key (id_materia)
)
```

Comment: Considera leer [ask], pues al menos a mi no me queda clara tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

La fecha actual:

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

El año de la fecha actual:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YY,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Aunque es redundante, modifico tu tabla para tener la Fecha y el Año.

```
create table materia
(
    id_materia varchar(4),
    nombre varchar(50),
    fecha datetime,
    Año int,
    Constraint pk_materia primary key (id_materia)
)
```

Agregamos los valores predeterminados que la base de datos introducirá de forma automática. Primero la fecha:

```
ALTER TABLE materia ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_materia_Fecha DEFAULT (GetDate()) FOR Fecha
```

Después el año:

```
ALTER TABLE materia ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_materia_Año DEFAULT (year(GetDate())) FOR Año
```

De esta forma cuando hagas una inserción del tipo

```
INSERT INTO materia (id_materia, nombre)
VALUES ('0001', 'una materia')
```

La base de datos introducirá de forma automática el campo Fecha y el campo Año.